# Any way to map a symmetric positive definite matric to another one with larger dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As a way of dimensionality reduction, if I have a SPD(Symmetric Positive Definite) matrix $X \in R^{n\times n}$, I can use a row full rank matrix $W \in R^{m \times n}, m<n$ to get a new small SPD matrix $Y = WXW^T, Y \in R^{m \times m}$. I can simply make $W$ a orthogonal one to meet the conditions.

However, what about I want a larger one. For example, how could I get $X$ from $Y$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It depends what properties you want to retain. Otherwise, you can always map everything to the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: It's still difficult without wider context, but one thing you can always do is directly embed the matrix in a larger zero matrix (i.e. have the top left $m \times m$ submatrix be $Y$, and put zeros everywhere else). Such a matrix will be positive semi-definite only, but I don't see much way around it. With the extra dimensions come extra eigenvalues, and if you set them to be anything other than $0$, you're going to run the risk of losing information about your original matrix.

Comment: I'm sorry not mention it. What I want is to recover X from Y as much as possible.  I am doing something like compression with a learnable W and someway to recover it.

Comment: sorry for comments because I dont know how to use the website and it's hard to write on mobile

Comment: Oh I think I see. You have some $W$ fixed, and you want to know how you can recover $X$ from $WXW^T$? If that's the case, then I'm pretty sure that's not possible. As you move to smaller dimensions, you're definitely going to lose information.

Comment: What I try to do is to retain most part of information not all. For example top k eigenvalues may take up most so it's ok to ignore others.

Comment: You can put the small matrix in the upper left corner, the way, @TheoBendit suggested, but fill up the rest of the diagonal with $1$, and all remaining elements with $0$ (that is, form the direct sum of your small matrix and an identity matrix of appropriate size). This will be an orthogonal matrix, and certainly contains all the information the smaller one contains.

Comment: And of course if you obtained the smaller one from a larger one the way you wrote, and $W^TW$ is an orthogonal projector (that is, $(W^TW)^2=W^TW$), then you should get back an approximation of $X$ by simply doing $W^TYW$.

Comment: BTW, how do you define an orthogonal matrix if it is not square?